# How to use group by in LINQ Asp c#

Tags: c#, linq

Reverse Engineering some reports that contain bad data.  Reports written in Asp.Net C# using Linq

I can write the query in the DB, but having trouble translating to Linq.

```
public StudentBehaviourActivityDTO GetStudentBehaviourActivity(
            Guid userId)
        {
            List<DateTime> lastUpdatedDates = Uow.ActivityTrackingUnitValues
                .Where(atuv => atuv.Last_Updated_On != null
                    && atuv.TBH_Activity_Tracking_Unit
                        .StudentBehaviour
                        .Student
                        .TeamMembers
                        .Any(tm => tm.Id == userId))
                        .Select(atuv => (DateTime)DbFunctions
                            .TruncateTime(atuv.Last_Updated_On))
                        .ToList();
```

What is this loading in the toList?
I assume this is loading my table: ActivityTrackingUnitValues

But then it also does then it also looks like it's joining these tables

```
.StudentBehaviour
.Student
.TeamMembers
```

I want to take the max(value) for Last_Updated_On and then group by student

Any help or explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies, my paste of code lost all formatting once I submitted the question

Comment: https://linqsamples.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is this loading in the toList?

Basically it seems it loads the last updated dates of the subjected user if he is in a team and updated ...

```
.StudentBehaviour
.Student
.TeamMembers
```

Those are navigational properties mainly translated into joins to get the desired data with relation to the table in hand.

so in details it does the following:

1. Gets the list of Activity Tracking Unit Values where:

   - The activity tracking unit value is updated
   - The student we are checking is a team member with the student whose behaviour is tracked by the unit responsible for this activity tracking unit value
2. Selects the day where those values are last updated

> I want to take the max(value) for Last_Updated_On and then group by student

compose the base dataset:

```
.Select(atuv => new 
{ 
    LastUpdatedDate = (DateTime)DbFunctions.TruncateTime(atuv.Last_Updated_On)),
    StudentId = atuv.TBH_Activity_Tracking_Unit.StudentBehaviour.Student.Id
})
```

group by student id:

```
.GroupBy(sd => sd.StudentId)
```

select student and it max last updated date:

```
.Select(sd => new { StudentId = sd.Key, MaxDate = sd.Max(d => d.LastUpdatedDate) });
```

finally it will look something like this:

```
var maxUpdatedDatePerStudentList = Uow.ActivityTrackingUnitValues
                    .Where(atuv => atuv.Last_Updated_On != null
                                && atuv.TBH_Activity_Tracking_Unit
                                       .StudentBehaviour
                                       .Student
                                       .TeamMembers
                                       .Any(tm => tm.Id == userId))
                    .Select(atuv => new 
                    { 
                        LastUpdatedDate = (DateTime)DbFunctions.TruncateTime(atuv.Last_Updated_On)),
                        StudentId = atuv.TBH_Activity_Tracking_Unit.StudentBehaviour.Student.Id
                    })
                    .GroupBy(sd => sd.StudentId)
                    .Select(sd => new { StudentId = sd.Key, MaxDate = sd.Max(d => d.LastUpdatedDate) })
                    .ToList();
```

and you can access its data like this:

```
maxUpdatedDatePerStudentList.ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine($"Student {g.StudentId} max updated date is {g.MaxDate}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public StudentBehaviourActivityDTO GetStudentBehaviourActivity(
        Guid userId)
    {
        List<DateTime> lastUpdatedDates = Uow.ActivityTrackingUnitValues
            .Where(atuv => atuv.Last_Updated_On != null // check to make sure it's not null
                && atuv.TBH_Activity_Tracking_Unit
                    .StudentBehaviour //this references a class (generally a join, but it doesn't join!)
                    .Student //this references a class (generally a join, but it doesn't join!)
                    .TeamMembers //this references a class (generally a join, but it doesn't join!)
                    .Any(tm => tm.Id == userId)) // Checks to make sure it isn't null or has a count greater than 0
                    .Select(atuv => (DateTime)DbFunctions
                        .TruncateTime(atuv.Last_Updated_On)) // Returns the truncatedtime and nowthing else
                    .ToList(); // converts it to a list
```

From what I can gather, it's making sure the class has members available.